Insert View Programmatically in storyboard designed Stackview in Swift iOS
I have created a stackview in storyboard which is having three buttons and I want to insert a separator in between all these three buttons, so I have created a separator blank view programmatically with frame CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 12) having gray colour. I am trying to insert this view in between all three buttons. But it's not working properly. I have option to add this separator on storyboard and hide-show that and it will work. But my buttons are dynamic in number so I want to insert separator programmatically in stackview.
How can we insert any view/any UI element programmatically in storyboard designed Stack view?
Storyboard:

Code:
@IBOutlet weak var mainStack: UIStackView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    let sep1 = getSeparatorView()
    let sep2 = getSeparatorView()
    let sep3 = getSeparatorView()
    mainStack.insertSubview(sep1, at: 1)
    mainStack.insertSubview(sep2, at: 3)
}

 func getSeparatorView() -> UIView {
        let separator = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 12))
        separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        return separator
    }

Note:
I tried by inserting insertArrangedSubview function but it looks like this (only one separator added with wrong width):
mainStack.insertArrangedSubview(sep1, at: 1)
        mainStack.insertArrangedSubview(sep2, at: 3)



Don't add it as a sub view, add it to the arrangedSubviews array

@Paulw11 I tried by arrangedSubviews as well. It's not looking properly still. Edited question, please check.

There is a misunderstanding here. The stackView in Storyboard was designed with auto layout, on the other hand, separator is using frame. It cannot be compatible. So:

As Paulw said, arrangedSubviews is the correct function.

mainStack.insertArrangedSubview(sep1, at: 1)
mainStack.insertArrangedSubview(sep2, at: 3)


Convert the separator's frame to constraints.

func getSeparatorView() -> UIView {
    ...
    separator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    separator.addConstraints([
        .init(item: separator, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 1),
        .init(item: separator, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 12)
    ])
    return separator
}


Change the stack properties for better layout, you can read the documentation here.

mainStack.spacing = 8
mainStack.distribution = .fill
mainStack.alignment = .center

Output:


Nice, clear answer. (Voted). Why did you make the separator in your answer 8 points wide though? It looks like the OP was trying for a 1-point-wide separator.

@DuncanC thank you. All I want to do is increase its visibility. Btw, I edited the answer xD
